# Import ANSI file to mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with column collation as : latin1_bin

I have a ANSI csv file which needs to be uploaded to table.

CASE 1: I import the file specifying character set of file as windows-1252 and 0 rows gets inserted.

CASE 2: I import the same file specifying character set of file as utf-8 and rows get inserted with question mark for the special characters.

What is causing the issue? How can i import ANSI file correctly to mysql database?

Comment: [**The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [**What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text**](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 0):

**Q: What's causing this?**

**A:** The MySQL `latin1` characterset is a single byte characterset. When a characterset translation is performed, any code points that don't map to a character in the target characterset will be converted to a default character. In your case, that's a question mark.

One quick test would be to load the data into a column that has a different characterset, e.g `utf8mb4` if you're using MySQL 5.5.

When reading the file, it's important that you specify the correct encoding.

I recommend you read the two blog posts I provided in comment to your question, and search for something like "UTF8 all the way through" in google, the source of knowledge. (I'll caution you that there's as much bad information (if not more) than good. Having a solid understanding of the basics is important; see those two blog posts I mentioned in the comment first.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any comment on the CASE 1 why no rows get imported.

Comment: Absent any information about how you are performing the "import", the operating system, what program you are using, the content of the file, the setting of `character_set_client` in the MySQL session...  **no**, I'd only be guessing... but one logical guess is that there's some mismatch between the actual encoding of the file, and the encoding that the "import" thinks the file is.

Comment: This is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4g876wopmihvzq/Book3.csv?dl=0 . Thanks for help. Its on windows 8 platform with default charset as windows-1252.